# adding data to dataset

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a dataset created in "visual studio".
when i open for with data grid it fills the data grid and i can see the data i have entered.
whan loading the form again the data is gone

I have used this code to create new data row.

```
            foreach (var ticket in esTicket)
            {
                databaseDataSet1.ES.AddESRow(ticket.esNum, ticket.title, ticket.link, ticket.open, ticket.escalated, ticket.downTime, ticket.startWork, ticket.endWork, ticket.toolID, ticket.toolType, ticket.openedBy);
            }
```

and also:

```
            foreach (var ticket in esTicket)
            {
                databaseDataSet1.ES.Rows.Add(ticket.esNum, ticket.title, ticket.link, ticket.open, ticket.escalated, ticket.downTime, ticket.startWork, ticket.endWork, ticket.toolID, ticket.toolType, ticket.openedBy);
            }
```

the inserted data just does not show

Comment: The DGV does not automatically repaint after data get changed.  The trick is to set the DataSource = null and then back to original data to get DGV to update.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your esTicket is a list. If so, I suggest that you could use another way to fill the datagridview without using dataset.

Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Student> list = new List<Student>();
            list.Add(new Student { Age=12,Name="Test1",Title="Hello" });
            list.Add(new Student { Age = 13, Name = "Test2", Title = "Hi" });
            list.Add(new Student { Age = 15, Name = "Test5", Title = "Greeting" });
            dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Student> list = (List<Student>)dataGridView1.DataSource;
            list.Add(new Student { Age = 16, Name = "Test6", Title = "Hello1" });
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
        }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }


    }
```

Result:
[image]